# send multiple emails using cfmail

Tags: coldfusion

I know I missing something very small here, but I am not able to get around this one. I have below queries.
I need 3 emails to go out to respective emails, but what is happening is only same email (content) is going out to the 3 users.
Any idea what is wrong here.

```
<cfquery name = getitems >
Select items, id, users
 from table1
</cfquery>

This below query returns say 3 users
<cfquery name = getusers >
Select name,email,id from table2
</cfquery>

<cfloop query=”getusers”>
<cfquery name = getuserdata dbtype=”query” >
Select * from getitems where id=#id#
</cfquery>
</cfloop>

<cfsavecontent variable=”test”>
<cfloop query=" getuserdata ">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(itemsarray)#" index="ii">
Build the email body
</cfloop>
</cfloop
</cfsavecontent>

<cfloop query=”getusers”>
<cfmail >
Send email to users
</cfmail>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: why are you building the email body in a separate loop than when you send it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a better way.

```
<cfquery name="theOnlyQueryYouShouldNeed">
select name, email, etc
from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
etc
</cfquery>

<cfmail query="theOnlyQueryYouShouldNeed"
to="#email#
etc>
build body here.  You can output variables with pound signs
only, no cfoutput tag required
</cfmail>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method Dan pointed out is better way to do things, but I will point out what is going wrong with your code.
You run the loop and storing all the values in single variable with savecontent. Now you run the loop again and same variable is sent to all users.

```
<cfquery name = getitems >
 Select items, id, users from table1
</cfquery>

<cfquery name = getusers >
 Select name,email,id from table2
 </cfquery>

<cfloop query=”getusers”>
  <cfquery name = getuserdata dbtype=”query” >
     Select * from getitems where id=#id#
 </cfquery>
<cfsavecontent variable=”test”>
 <cfloop query=" getuserdata ">
   <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(itemsarray)#" index="ii">
 Build the email body
</cfloop>
</cfloop>
   </cfsavecontent>
<!--- so basically, you need to send email within the same loop in which you are generating your savecontent variable--->
 <cfmail >
   Send email to users
  </cfmail>
</cfloop>
```